# How to associate hash-named .wsp files to my tagged graphite metrics?

Tags: grafana, graphite, whisper

I used graphite tagged metrics over grafana and whisper, but http://graphite/tags/delSeries removes something but not .wsp files.
And untagged metrics creates .wsp files in whisper data folder with human-readable names, but tagged metrics creates only hash-named folders and .wsp files in _tagged directory.
Like so:

```
/whisper
  /data
    /Players
      registrations.wsp
      today_registrations.wsp
    /Gaming
      playing_count.wsp
    /_tagged
      /f58
        /010
          f58010d4cef67599a31f4daaab4a53c4d7fd85a9faea546282d2058c40c7e7b9.wsp
      /f56
        /031
          f56031052aec89dc9cc38e44dbe71b2eb08fb513a3e60d515eb1dc23f5b929d1.wsp
```

How to know .wsp file associated with my tagged metric?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just running into that problem as well, how to map the actual path/tag metric to its corresponding hashed wsp file.
I don't think you can compute the actual metric name from the hash, but you can do the other way around, by using graphite's encoding methods.

I've quickly written a python script just for lab purpose:
  - It can take several metric names in parameters and returns a mapping

Just log into your graphite host and create a python script in **/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/tags**

```py
#!/opt/graphite/bin/python3

import sys
from utils import TaggedSeries

for line in sys.stdin:
    paths = line.split()
    for path in paths:
        # Normalize first
        parsed = TaggedSeries.parse(path)
        print(  path + " -> /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/" + TaggedSeries.encode(parsed.path,'/',True) + ".wsp")
```

You can then pipe a list of metrics:

```
#  echo "users.count;server=s1" |python mapper.py
users.count;server=s1 -> /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/_tagged/b6c/c91/b6cc916d608e4b145b318669606e79118cc41d316f96735dd43621db4fd2bcaf.wsp
```

You can also get all your tagged metrics and generate a file that you can later cat into the script. In this example i get all metrics associated associated with the tag 'server':

```
# curl -s "http://localhost/tags/findSeries?expr=server=~." | sed s/"\", \""/\\n/g > my_metrics
```

Then cat your metrics:

```
# cat my_metrics | python mapper.py
```

That's a starting point. From there you can easily do some simple scripting for deleting wsp files, like the ones not updated since a month by example.

[graphite](/questions/tagged/graphite)